# Media Title appearing in View when HTML is stripped

Tags: views, media

I've run into an issue with media in a view. I have a view using bootstrap grid to display body field content. The view field content being displayed is setup to strip out HTML, but the word "Image" is inserted where a media entity was. Not sure if the word "Image" is a leftover from media or the entity embed module.

example:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get rid of this unnecessary word?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a media field label and not the media type name, like I originally thought it to be.

This was happening due to the media label being set to "Visually Hidden" instead of "Hidden"

This setting can be found at
Administration > Structure > Media types > [your media type] > Manage Display

Now that it's set to "Hidden" it no longer shows in the label in the view or the WYSIWYG